# stable diffusion automatic 1111, ckpt

Tags: google-colaboratory, ckpt

now "path to ckpt" no longer exists in stable diffusion automatic 1111... it has been replaced by path_to_model or model_link.
It doesn't work to use the path "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Fast-Dreambooth/Sessions/"blabla"/"filename".ckpt...

does anyone know how to do it now?
I'm using google colab